# Iterate through Binary search tree java

Tags: java, loops, binary-search-tree

Can some one show me the way to loop a binary tree in order to traverse all nodes.
I will add students by insert method.
I just want to print all the students objects.
This is my BST :

```
public class BinarySearchTree<Students extends Comparable<? super Student>> {
    public static BinaryNode root;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        this.root = null;
    }

public void insert(Student student) {

        root = insert(student, root);
    }

    protected BinaryNode<Student> insert(Student student, BinaryNode<Student> t) {
        if (t == null) {

            t = new BinaryNode<Student>(student);
        } else if (student.compareTo(t.element) < 0) {
            t.left = insert(student, t.left);
        } else if (student.compareTo(t.element) > 0) {
            t.right = insert(student, t.right);
        } else {
            // throw new DuplicateItemException(student.toString());
        }
        return t;
    }
}
```

Node Class :

```
class BinaryNode<Student> {
    // Constructor
    BinaryNode(Student theElement) {
        element = theElement;
        left = right = null;
    }

    // Data; accessible by other package routines
    Student element; // The data in the node
    BinaryNode<Student> left; // Left child
    BinaryNode<Student> right; // Right child
}
```

Comment: Your insert method never assigns to root, it just returns newly created node and that return value is never used.

Comment: I think that you have some issues in your insert method

Comment: I have edited code.

Answer (score 1):

Add this method to the `BinarySearchTree` class:

```
public void inorder(BinaryNode node) {
    if (node == null) {
        return;
    }
    inorder(node.left);
    System.out.print(...); //whatever you want to do with the node
    inorder(node.right);
}
```

In a similar way you can do **preorder** and **postorder** traversals.

Comment: Its only print one node. I have inserted 2 students. After calling inorder() its print only one.

Comment: Actullay, Im looking something similar to this
BinarySearchTree<Student> students;
for(Student student : Students)
{}

Comment: Everybody gave you the same answers. We can't all be wrong. You can't iterate BinarySearchTree class using for loop. Your insert method never assigns to root.

Comment: I think it won't work because `inorder()` doesn't have an argument. It should  be something like `inorder(BinaryNode node)`

Comment: I think that this method have some mistakes. The declared does not have parameter, but in the body it call it-self with parameter

Answer (score 0):

```
public class BinarySearchTree<Students extends Comparable<? super Student>> {
    public static BinaryNode root;

    public BinarySearchTree() {
        this.root = null;
    }
    ...
    public void print() {
        print(root);
    }

    public void print(BinaryNode<Student> node) {
        if (node == null) {
            return;
        }
        print(node.left);
        doSomething(node.getStudent());
        print(node.right);
    }
}
```

Comment: Its only print one node.
I have inserted 2 students.
After calling print() its print only one.

Comment: Actullay, Im looking something similar to this
BinarySearchTree<Student> students;
for(Student student : Students)
{}

Answer (score 0):

There are 3 ways to traverse Binary Search Trees.

- **Pre-order**

  ```
  public void preOrder(BinaryNode node) {
      if (node == null) {
          return;
      }
      doSomethig(node.element); // process node
      preOrder(node.left);
      preOrder(node.right);
  }
  ```
- **In-order** in this case nodes are traversed in order

  ```
  public void inOrder(BinaryNode node) {
      if (node == null) {
          return;
      }
      inOrder(node.left);
      doSomethig(node.element); // process node
      inOrder(node.right);
  }
  ```
- **Post-order**

  ```
  public void postOrder(BinaryNode node) {
      if (node == null) {
          return;
      }
      postOrder(node.left);
      postOrder(node.right);
      doSomethig(node.element); // process node
  }
  ```

You have to choose one of these and run for example:

```
    preOrder(root); // where root is a handle to your BST
```